# Why do I have to create a new account for every StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I just had a question migrated from DIY to gardening, and now I can no longer edit my question unless I create an account with the gardening exchange despite me adding it to "my communities" under the stackexchange drop-down.  Why can't we just have one StackExchange login to rule them all?

Answer (score 4):

You have separate accounts because you expertise is different in different areas.

Your 1.5k rep on DIY is not relevant when it comes to other topics like Chemistry or Photography (for example). With > 200 rep on one site you *do* get the 100 point account association bonus that lets you upvote, flag and comment on a new site as you've demonstrated that you know how to do these actions. Every other privilege you need to earn by demonstrating domain knowledge.

If you use the same OpenID to sign into Gardening as you used here then the accounts should be automatically associated and you will be able to edit your question.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense.  I understand I have different "Karma accounts", but I only have one "user account".  I'm active in SO, DIY, and a few others.  I just don't understand why I can't be simply "user logged-in" to stackexchange and simply add different exchanges to my user.

Comment: @Paul you have different accounts on each site. They are all linked underneath your Stack Exchange account, but they are separate.

Comment: I log in with google or facebook or whatever which usually requires that I log out of my current FB user session (my "personal" session) and log into my "public" persona, and then come back to StackExchange to follow through with the login process to associate a new user account with my current user and... well it's never worth it and migrated questions simply stagnate.  I just wish things were a bit different...

Comment: @Paul perhaps you need to create a Stack Exchange Open ID - https://openid.stackexchange.com/ - and use that to log into SE sites with.

Comment: Yes.  Another account/user/password is exactly what i need...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_fatigue  Sorry to vent -- It's just that as a user logged into several stackexchages already (all associated), I "feel" logged into StackExchange in general.  But in actuality, I am not and "need" more online ID.  There's probably a better place for this discussion, but It probably requires that I log in to different Meta!..  Thanks for your time!  Sincerely.

Comment: @Paul - this does come up on a regular basis and there's probably no chance that things will change,

Answer (score 1):

This is simply bad planning/coding by SE developers.  You shouldn't have to sign up for each site.  There seems to be a contingent at SE that thinks (at least from a meta by an employee on another site) that people don't want to be automatically signed up for a site upon first touch... whatever.

Like I care if I belong to 5, 10, 50, or 500 SE sites.  This is simply a bad user experience and stemmed from initial problems that have had with open IDs - a few years ago.  I understand their initial issue because the open ID environment was once horrible, but I don't understand what the issue is now.  Get user ID from the POST data, cross-reference the salts from various sites, and autologin user cross-checked on POST data and hash... This isn't rocket science.